# How to reconstruct the path of a 2d maze after using BFS to find the shortest path

Tags: c++

I've implemented the Breath first search algorithm in C++ as shown below, I know the algorithm works and finds the shortest path from a given room to one of the exits. But due to the nature of the algorithm, it does not find the actual path, but instead the number of steps taken to get from start node to end node.

I'm trying to reconstruct the shortest path found using this algorithm. I stored a record of the parent node for each node visited in a matrix that is the same size as my maze. Since each node will have an x and y coordinate, I made two parent matrixes, one for the x and one for the y (not sure if this is the right approach).

I'm having trouble implementing a function to reconstruct the path. From what I've read im suppose to loop from the end node to the start node in the parent matrix but how do I actually do this? I dont even know how to conceptualize doing this.

```
int bfs(string maze[row][col],bool visited[row][col],int prevx[row][col],int prevy[row][col],int x,int y,int &endx, int &endy){
int nodes_left = 1; // tracks how many nodes we need to dequeue before taking a step
int move_count = 0; //tracks the number of steps taken
bool foundExit = false;
int curx, cury;
rq.push(y);
cq.push(x);
visited[y][x] = true;
while (rq.size()>0){
    cury = rq.front();
    curx = cq.front();
    rq.pop();
    cq.pop();
    if (maze[cury][curx] == " E2"){
        foundExit = true;
        endx = 0;
        endy = 8;
        break;
    }
    if(maze[cury][curx] == " E4"){
        foundExit = true;
        endx = 12;
        endy = 14;
        break;
    }
    check_nodes(maze,prevx,prevy,visited,curx,cury);
    //tracking the number of steps to exit the maze
    nodes_left--;
    if (nodes_left == 0){
        nodes_left = next_nodes;
        next_nodes = 0;
        move_count++;
    }
}
if(foundExit){
    return move_count;
}
return -1;
```

}

```
void check_nodes(string maze[row][col],int prevx[row][col],int prevy[row][col],bool visited[row][col],int curx, int cury){
int newy,newx;
//checking all 4 possible directions
for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++){
    newy = cury + dr[i];        //updating new y coordinate corresponding to the row
    newx = curx + dc[i];        //updating new x coordinate corresponding to the column
    if (validMove(maze,visited,newx,newy)){ //checking if move is valid, i.e not out of bounds, visited, or blocked.
        rq.push(newy);           //adding new coordinates to the queue
        cq.push(newx);
        visited[newy][newx] = true;  //marking visited to ensure that it cannot be added to the queue multiple times
        prevy[newy][newx] = cury;
        prevx[newy][newx] = curx;
        next_nodes++;               //moving to the next layer of nodes
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your code doesn’t seem to be self-consistent: you declare `prev` but use `prevx` and `prevy`.  A working example is much easier to evaluate and *complete* as well as debug.

Comment: True, just noticed those errors when I was editing it this morning. I made the necessary changes. The only reason I didnt post the whole code was that this is due in 2 days for my C++ class and I did not want a fellow student in my class to copy pasta my code at the last minute. Is there a way I could send you the entire thing privately? (thats if you'd allow it).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost there. You just have to literally do what you said: reconstruct the path from end to start. I think you are struggling in how to implement that. I will write the code of that part using the variables you used. I will use a `vector<pair<int, int> >` to build the path. Every element of this vector is a pair in which its first value is the x coordinate and its second value is the y coordinate. As the path will be built from end to start, it should be reversed at the end of the algorithm.

```cpp
vector<pair<int, int> > path;
int endx = 0, endy = 8; // this is one of the exit coordinates according your code
int startx = 0, starty = 0; // this is not necessarily your start position
int curx = endx, cury = endy; // current position while building the path backwards
while(curx != startx || cury != starty) {
    path.push_back(make_pair(curx, cury));
    int tempx = prevx[curx][cury]; // notice that is necessary to use temporal variable
    int tempy = prevy[curx][cury]; // to prevent overwriting curx that was immediately used
    curx = tempx;
    cury = tempy;
}
reverse(path.begin(), path.end()); // reversing the path to its correct order
```

Comment: Thank you, ive implemented the code you wrote as a function, however, the size of the path vector pair is 1, therefore when i print the elements im only seeing the starting coordinates.

Comment: There was a error in the while loop condition. Now it is fixed.

Comment: That fixed it, and to think just changing 'and' to 'or' did the trick. I need to go over this code again and again until I understand whats going. Man I cannot thank you enough. I would upvote but I dont have 15 rep.